Sci-Fi book series where a man awakens to find his brain inside a space probe launched into space
This is a trilogy about a man waking up with his brain implanted into a space probe. His eyes and ears are the sensors. He travels through space learning about the universe.

There are lots of these.   Can you think of any more details?

Not what you're looking for, but a person chooses to dump his brain into a spaceship in the third book of The ThreeBody Problem.

This sounds like the "Bobiverse" series (there's a 4th book now) by Dennis E. Taylor.  The first book We Are Legion (We Are Bob) (2016) starts with the titular Bob being resurrected by a future theocratic U.S. successor state called FAITH.  He gets implanted into a probe and sent into space.
The blurb on Goodreads states:

Bob Johansson has just sold his software company and is looking forward to a life of leisure. There are places to go, books to read, and movies to watch. So it's a little unfair when he gets himself killed crossing the street.
Bob wakes up a century later to find that corpsicles have been declared to be without rights, and he is now the property of the state. He has been uploaded into computer hardware and is slated to be the controlling AI in an interstellar probe looking for habitable planets. The stakes are high: no less than the first claim to entire worlds. If he declines the honor, he'll be switched off, and they'll try again with someone else. If he accepts, he becomes a prime target. There are at least three other countries trying to get their own probes launched first, and they play dirty.
The safest place for Bob is in space, heading away from Earth at top speed. Or so he thinks. Because the universe is full of nasties, and trespassers make them mad - very mad.


Even Science-Fiction isn't immune to Isekai tropes I see.
